# angular ui-router dynamic anchor

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

here's the situation.
I have dynamic generated anchor inside a view (eg id is `id="{{replace(indice[1])}}"`) and everything works well when I'm inside the view. The problem happens if I try to reach that anchor from another view. I get the correct url `costituzione/#/altre-costituzioni#la-costituzione-del-regno-unito`, but the page doesn't scroll till the anchor.
i use:

```
ui-sref="altrec({'#': '{{replace(indice[1])}}'})"
```

and the state is:

```
 var altreState = {
        name: 'altrec',
        url: '/altre-costituzioni',
        templateUrl: 'costituzioni/altrec.html',
        controller: function($scope){
          $scope.indice =["Quando e perchè sono nate le Costituzioni",
                         "La Costituzione del Regno Unito",
                         "La Costituzione americana",
                         "La Costituzione francese",
                         "La legge fondamentale della Germania",
                         "La costituzione spagnola"

                          ];
         $scope.bandiera=["img/why.png",
                          "img/bandiera_inghilterra.png",
                          "img/bandiera_americana.png",
                          "img/bandiera_francese.png",
                          "img/bandiera_germania.png",
                          "img/bandiera_spagna.png"

                           ]
          $scope.replace= function(newStr){
            newStr = newStr.replace(/\s/g, "-").toLowerCase();
            return newStr;
          }
        }
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use `$anchorScroll` to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, i looked for the  $anchorscroll doc, but I couldn't make it work...